# Queries inside of a connection query callback

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to fetch a table, whose name is defined in another table and return the results.

I have defined a database module with these methods:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var config = require("../config/database.js");

module.exports = {
    pool: mysql.createPool({
        host: config.host,
        user: config.user,
        database: config.database,
        password: config.password,
    }),

    getConnection: function(callback) {
        this.pool.getConnection(callback);
    },

    fetch: function(table, callback) {
        this.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if(err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM ??", table, callback);
                connection.release();
            }
        });
    },
};
```

I am trying to fetch the table and then the "sub" table like so:

```
db.fetch("foo", function(err, rows) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        _.each(rows, function(row) {
            db.fetch(row.tbl, function(err, result) { console.log(err, result); });
        });
    }
});
```

However the inner-fetch callback is never called.

Why is this? I suspected I needed to close the first connection before establishing a second so I tried taking the `each` loop outside but encountered things becoming out of sync.

Comment: If you comment out the `connection.release` line in your database module, does the callback fire?  Is this an async issue where the query hasn't finished by the time you release the connection on the next line?

Comment: Removing the `connection.release` doesn't work. Yes, it's an async issue, but I added in code to make it wait and discovered that the inner query wasn't being called.